# Change datatype from string to integer in MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a set of documents where some of `product_id` are stored in string

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("foobar1"),
    "product_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("foobar2"),
    "product_id": 2
  }
]
```

Is there any way to convert `product_id` to integer for all the documents using MongoDB PHP ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also search for the specific type. Check out the documentation of [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/). Strings are `$type: 2`

```
db.collection.find({
    product_id: {
        $type: 2
    }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.product_id = new NumberInt(doc.product_id);
    db.product.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(product) {
    product.product_id= new NumberInt(product.product_id);
    db.collection.save(product);
});
```

OR using UPDATE

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.collection.update({_id:data._id},{$set:{product_id:parseInt(data.product_id)}});
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already aware of doing this via Mongo Shell. I'm looking for something in MongoDB PHP, as its clearly mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Better and simpler approach would be doing it in the MongoShell itself, the below javascript function will does the job of converting all `product_id` from String to integer.

This will work if all the product_id string can be converted to an integer, say the possible values of product_id can be "1", "34343", "23", ....

```
db.collection.find({product_id: {$exists : true}}).forEach(
    function(obj) { 
        obj.product_id = new NumberInt( obj.product_id );
        db.collection.save(obj);
    }
);
```

Comment: But aren't you going through all documents this way? `"product_id": "1"` exists as much as `"product_id": 2` exists.

Comment: yes it goes thru all documents, the first condition is to ensure that `product_id` is present in the document.